# Global memory problems when the MOT feature is used in the openGauss database

Tags: open-gauss

In the openGauss database, data is inserted into the MOT table but is not submitted. When the mot_global_memory_detail() is used to check the global memory, the global memory keeps increasing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Inserts will use global memory for rows and index keys, if you rollback the transaction the memory will be released back. That's the reason why you see global memory increasing even though the transaction is not committed yet.